# Windows local hostname resolution fails on reconnect

Tags: windows-10, networking, hostname

TL;DR version

Windows fails to resolve local hostnames on reconnect network reconnect.

```
Right after boot, network connected. 
> ping ubuntu 
Reply from [...]

I disconnect and reconnect.
> ping ubuntu
Ping request could not find host ubuntu. Please check the name and try again.
```

**I can always ping/connect/ssh using the ip address from the router page.**

Kindly do not suggest static ip, modifying the hosts file etc to 'fix' this issue. I'm interested in knowing why it works before reconnect, and doesn't after, and how ot fix it.

---

Longer version (please read TL;DR too):

1. I boot up my computer
2. Connect to my local private home network via WiFi
3. I ping my raspberry pi on the network, and get these results
4. Windows pc

   ```
   PS C:\Users\username> ping ubuntu

   Pinging ubuntu.local [xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx%4] with 32 bytes of data:
   Reply from xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx%4: time=4ms
   [...]

   PS C:\Users\username> ping -4 ubuntu

   Pinging ubuntu.local [192.168.1.10] with 32 bytes of data:
   Reply from 192.168.1.10: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64
   [...]

   PS C:\Users\username> nslookup ubuntu
   Server:  R7800
   Address:  192.168.1.1
   *** No internal type for both IPv4 and IPv6 Addresses (A+AAAA) records available for ubuntu

   PS C:\Users\username> nslookup ubuntu.local
   Server:  R7800
   Address:  192.168.1.1

   *** R7800 can't find ubuntu.local: Non-existent domain
   ```

   From pi

   ```
   ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ping r7800.local
   PING r7800.local (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
   64 bytes from R7800 (192.168.1.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.981 ms
   [...]

   ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ping username-pc.local
   PING username-pc.local (192.168.1.14) 56(84) bytes of data.
   64 bytes from 192.168.1.14 (192.168.1.14): icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=2.73 ms
   [...]
   ```
5. Now, I disconnect and reconnect to my WiFi. Repeating the same tests, I get this

   ```
   PS C:\Users\username> ping ubuntu
   Ping request could not find host ubuntu. Please check the name and try again.
   ```

   From my pi

   ```
   ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ping r7800.local
   PING r7800.local (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
   64 bytes from R7800 (192.168.1.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.974 ms
   [...]

   ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ping username-pc.local
   ping: username-pc.local: Name or service not known
   ```

```
PS C:\Users\username> ipconfig /all

    Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
        Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165
        Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
        DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
        Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
        Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx%4(Preferred)
        IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.14(Preferred)
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
        Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 22 September 2020 23:50:28
        Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 23 September 2020 23:50:29
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
        DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
        DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : xxxxxxxxx
        DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-0x-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
        DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
        NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

I tried all the network reset methods, from netsh commands to ipconfig commands, and even did a full windows network reset (`Settings > Home > Network & Internet > Status > Network reset (at the bottom)`).

On reboot, I can ping again. If I disconnect and reconnect, ping no longer works again.

As shown above, I checked my raspberry pi to narrow the problem down by trying to ping other devices from them, so I think I can safely rule out the router or the pi at fault. What could be the issue in windows that's causing this? I'm on Windows 2004 (`20H1`), with the latest updates. My router is R7800 running on the latest Voxel firmware.

If I can give any more info, do let me know, thanks.

Comment: What happens if you use the IP address and not the hostname?  Does it work then?

Comment: Yes, I'll add that in.

Comment: (1) When it happens, try the command `ipconfig /flushdns`. (2) In registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NlaSvc\Parameters\Internet` set the value of DWORD item `EnableActiveProbing` to `1`. (3) Ensure your network adapter (what is it) has the latest driver, (4) Try another wifi adapter.

Comment: I have also had this problem in the past and nothing else resolved it.  If after trying what other people suggest, you might try assigning static IPs and putting the hostnames in the hosts file.  Thats what I did.  Ugly but the problem went away.

Comment: @harrymc 1, 2, 3 done. No change. I'll check with a USB adapter tomorrow and report back